# Trailhead Community feed not working

Tags: trailhead

When I am logged into my Trailhead  home page, the community feed is not working.  I've tried clearing cache.  It's been this way for me for a while

[image]

Comment: This is probably better of being raised through the trailhead help page. Remember that we're not an official part of Salesforce here, and >= 99% of us are customers like yourself.